# Running a build for App Store using Expo and getting this error: "Compatible versions of some pods could not be resolved"

Tags: ios, expo, app-store

I have published an app on Google Play and it works just fine. I'm trying to publish the same app on Apples App Store and keep getting this error:

"Build failed: Compatible versions of some pods could not be resolved.
You are seeing this error because either:

- Some of the pods used in your project depend on different versions of the same pod. See logs for more information.
- If you are caching Podfile.lock using "cache" field in eas.json, then versions there might not match required values in Podspecs of some installed libraries. To fix this, you can re-run build command with "--clear-cache" option, or select "Clear cache and retry build" on the build page."

I have tried clearing the cache on the Expo build page but this did not resolve the error. What else should I do to resolve this issue? Any help would be appreciated.